# jQuery code disabling links to other web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have some jQuery code that allows for smoothing scrolling on my web pages.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where the button will appear
    var offset = 200,
        
    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,
    
    // bind with the button
    $back_to_top = $('.back-to-top');

    // display and hide the button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('make-visible-btt') : $back_to_top.removeClass('make-visible-btt');
    });

    //smooth scroll to top
    $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 ,
            }, scroll_top_duration
        );
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where the button will appear
  var offset = 200,

    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,

    // bind with the button
    $back_to_top = $('.back-to-top');

  // display and hide the button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $back_to_top.addClass('make-visible-btt'): $back_to_top.removeClass('make-visible-btt');
  });

  //smooth scroll to top
  $back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
  });
});
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url(../images/back-to-top.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.make-visible-btt {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#last">jump to last section</a>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section" id="last"></div>
<a href="/my-web-page/" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

The code works fine. When users click the "back to top" button on the page, they're automatically smooth scrolled to the top. All good.

[image]

The code above, however, **doesn't work for in-page links**.

```
<a href="/my-web-page/#section-3">text text text</a>
```

So if a user clicks on a link like the one above, the pages instantly jumps to that section (which is the default behavior).

I added this code to fix that problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event){
    var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href'), 
        skip = false;
    if (!skip) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where the button will appear
  var offset = 200,

    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,

    // bind with the button
    $back_to_top = $('.back-to-top');

  // display and hide the button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $back_to_top.addClass('make-visible-btt'): $back_to_top.removeClass('make-visible-btt');
  });

  //smooth scroll to top
  $back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event){
    var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href'), 
        skip = false;
    if (!skip) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url(../images/back-to-top.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.make-visible-btt {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#last">jump to last section</a>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section" id="last"></div>
<a href="/my-web-page/" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

So now that's fixed.

But that second code block has created **two new problems**:

1. Links with a fragment identifier (e.g., `#section-of-page`) no longer update in the browser address bar. For example, within a page, on click, the page does scroll smoothly to the target section (so it works), but the web address stays fixed at `www.website.com/whatever`, when it should update to `www.website.com/whatever#section-of-page`.
2. Links with a fragment identifier don't work across pages. In other words, `/this-web-page#section-of-page` works fine. But `/another-web-page#section-of-page` and `www.another-website.com/whatever#section-of-page` both fail (click does nothing).

These problems didn't exist before adding that second code block.

Looking for some guidance on how to fix these problems.

Also if you can suggest a way to integrate all functions into one block of code, that would be great.

Lastly, I know about the CSS `scroll-behavior` property, but it's still very rudimentary (can't adjust any settings), so I'd rather stick with JS for now.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you specify a path instead of just the fragment identifier in the `href`?

Comment: The site uses the `base` element, which sets a fixed initial path for all pages. Each page works off of that. @Unmitigated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `href` points to an internal location by creating a `URL` object from it and checking its `host` against `window.location.host`. Then call `event.preventDefault` and perform smooth scrolling only in that case.

The callback function (third argument) to `$.animate` can be used to set the hash properly after the scrolling effect.

```
if (new URL(href, window.location).host === window.location.host) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 500, function() {
        window.location.hash = new URL(href, window.location).hash;
    });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where the button will appear
  var offset = 200,

    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,

    // bind with the button
    $back_to_top = $('.back-to-top');

  // display and hide the button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $back_to_top.addClass('make-visible-btt'): $back_to_top.removeClass('make-visible-btt');
  });

  //smooth scroll to top
  $back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event){
    var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href');
    if (new URL(href, window.location).host === window.location.host) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 500, function() {
            window.location.hash = new URL(href, window.location).hash;
        });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url(../images/back-to-top.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.make-visible-btt {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#last">jump to last section</a>
<a href="https://example.com">External link</a>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section" id="last"></div>
<a href="/my-web-page/" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

for The `1st` problem is because of `event.preventDefault();`. If you remove this line then browser url will be updated accordingly.

if you see any problems then you try setting the url again after animation completes / finishes.

for syntax [refer docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
```

For `2nd` problem

check wether the callback is hitting on click by putting debug point